Getting wrong date and time when converting a zulu time
I'm trying to format a given zulu time but it returns a wrong date and time.
$yourDate = "2024-07-16T11:29:32.347043421Z";
echo date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime($yourDate));

Above will return 1970-01-01 12:00:00. But it returns correct if there are only 8 decimal palaces. The below script works but I don't know for other values.
$yourDate = "2024-07-16T11:29:32.347043421Z";
$trimmedDate = substr($yourDate, 0, 26) . "Z"; 
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($trimmedDate));


I can't duplicate it: https://3v4l.org/ARL9E

What's your PHP version?

@HonkderHase PHP Version 7.3.23

Yeah, it happens there... PHP8.0.10 has fixed it, prior to this, you'll get 1970 date... you should consider update PHP since your version is long dead!


Online Demo Here : https://onecompiler.com/php/42kertuvz


PHP Version 7.3 Demo : https://onlinephp.io/c/55c29

<?php

$yourDate = "2024-07-16T11:29:32.347043421Z";

// Remove the Z (Zulu time indicator) and extra nanoseconds
$yourDate = substr($yourDate, 0, 23) . 'Z';

// Create a DateTime object from the string
$date = new DateTime($yourDate, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));

// Format the date and time as You needed
$formattedDate = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.u');

echo $formattedDate;

?>

